# Bosch eBike wiring diagram, where to find?

Tags: repair, electric-bike, electronics, electric-power

My RieseMüllerPackster80 refused to start today.

I *guess* there is a bad connection somewhere but as all I could do was plugging the battery and computer in and out, I am not wiser whether cabling has come loose, the computer has decided to end its life or something else.

Hence I'd like a wiring diagram so I can track that at least the wiring is OK.

I have searched the Internet but to no avail. Anyone knows where to find a wiring diagram for a Bosch Intuvia Active/Performance line?

I am primarily asking for the cables going throughout the bike
but also for the connectors at the computer.